# Intuition behind the cumulative distribution function for a certain case

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, rademacher-distribution

I found the following the example of a cumulative distribution function:

Suppose that $X$ takes only the discrete values $0$ and $1$ with an equal probability on the interval $[0,1]$.
Then the CDF of $X$ is given by

$F(x) = \begin{cases}
0 &:\ x < 0\\
1/2 &:\ 0 \le x < 1\\
1 &:\ x \ge 1.
\end{cases} $

However, I do not really understand how one reaches this result. The cases for $x \lt 0$ and $x \ge1$ follow by definition. However the case $0 \le x \lt 1$ appears to be rather obscure:

E.g. $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and comparing these two distributions, then $F(x)$ is bigger given the non-discrete distribution than in the uniform distribution for $0 \le x \lt 0.5$.

I don't have a proper understanding yet, how to arrive at above's CDF. I would be very happy, if someone could enlighten me.

Comment: $F(x) = P(X\le x)$, and $P(X=0) = P(X=1) = 1/2$, so ...

Comment: Let $0\le x<1$. Then $\{X\le x\}$ occurs if and only if $X=0$, which has a probability of $1/2$. Therefore, $F_X(x)=1/2$.